# Query regarding the internal access control of swift language introduced in XCode 6 beta 4

Tags: swift, access-control, internals

Being from a Java background I was bit confused when I saw the `internal` access control of newly introduced Swift language.

In Java when **No access specifier** is being added to a field or method then its assumed that the `access modifier` implemented on that field or method is `default` which has `package level access`.

As this update on official Swift blog on 23rd July 2014 for XCode 6 beta 4 states:

> internal : entities are available to the entire module that includes the definition (e.g. an app or framework target).

Now in Java `modules` and `packages` are used interchangeably, so as per the definition of `internal` in Swift language its available to the entire module that includes the definition, for eg: an app as stated in the blog.

So does `modules` mean the full app in Swift language?

If that's the case then `public` and `internal` will be serving the same purpose, but I suppose that's should not the case. I thought that `internal` is meant for package/module level access, but now confused seeing the example provided just after the definition of `internal access control` on the blog.

[image: internal definition on the blog]

I would be interested in clarifications on these points, as I am starting into a new language and I don't want to grasp any wrong interpretation of the features of the language.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a framework and use internal then that function or property is only available in that framework. When using that framework in an other app (module) then that app will not be able to access that function. It will when you use public.